# How to append something before a particular div with a random number

Tags: jquery

I want to append a div inside a div which have many divs inside itself. My code is shown below:

```
<div id="main">
<div class="random no"></div>
<div class="random no"></div>
<div class="random no"></div>
<div class="random no"></div>
<div class="mydiv"></div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code is:

```
$("#main").append("<div class='random no'> </div>");
```

But it appends after the last child of div "main". How to insert that div before `#mydiv`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("<div class='random no'> </div>").insertBefore("#main .mydiv");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jMaQq/1/)**

**or**

```
$("#main .mydiv").before("<div class='random no'> </div>");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jMaQq/5/)**

**or**

```
$('#main').append("<div class='random no'> Random no</div>").after($(".mydiv"))​;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jMaQq/7/)**

**Related refs:**

- **[after()](http://api.jquery.com/after)**
- **[.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before)**
- **[.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore)**

Comment: +1 for your persistance to add more and more good code to your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#main").find(".mydiv").before("#yourDivToBeInserted");
```